# Where do I find what to put in queries to openFEC

Tags: api, openfec

Trying to use the [openFEC API](https://api.open.fec.gov/developers/) but can't make the most simple query. Trying to search for current candidates, I need a "district" and a "cycle" but have no idea where to get this information.

Comment: opened this issue up on their github repo. i asked for candidate id data, sorry it was the first demo i tried, but hopefully they'll respond and then i can ask for your specific data https://github.com/18F/openFEC/issues/1335

Answer (score 3):

You can cycle through candidates at the `candidates` endpoint:
https://api.open.fec.gov/v1/candidates/?sort_nulls_large=true&api_key=DEMO_KEY&sort=name&per_page=20&page=1
which provides you with every piece of information you need to perform queries (I think)...
More information on GitHub where I asked 18f for support:
https://github.com/18F/openFEC/issues/1335